# Can python share info like .net remoting?

Tags: python, process, remoting, communication

I known python can use pipe to communicate between two process of py.

But, data and functions of this method are not clear.

I like .net remoting better.

So, can python realize that approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this using (for example) [PYRO](http://www.xs4all.nl/~irmen/pyro3/) (Python Remote Objects).

Answer (score 0):

The ability to share "data and functions" is better known as a web service or remote procedure call (RPC). This has the benefit of working between nearly any computer language on any operating system, whereas ".net remoting" will mainly only work on a Windows computer between programs written in a .net technology.

There are many Python libraries supporting various web service and RPC protocols.

http://docs.python.org/library/xmlrpclib.html

http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebServices